# problem in finding the big O notation ordering from lower complexity to higher complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I'm a mechanical student studying data structures in Coursera. I got an assignment for ordering the time complexity lower to the higher time given below in the image. my answer was showing wrong and I'd like to know where I have done the mistake. [The problem statement is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3LI0.png). I thought it was correct but I'm a beginner to this, so please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: this just need a basic linear algebra knowledge, as value of n increase you need to see the change in the function and then rank them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As the growth of `sqrt{n}` is faster than `\log{n}`, `3` should be first and then `7`. To better know this, suppose `n = 2^(2k)`. We will have `\log{n} = 2k` and `sqrt{n} = 2^k`. Notice that you have done well for other cases.